# How to get the cluster state of Solr Cloud using the solrZkClient and zkStateReader?

Tags: java, solr, apache-zookeeper

I've downloaded and installed Solr (SolrCloud) v. 4.10.3 on my local system, and can run it without any problems, index documents, interact with its web UI. I can also use the following command line to interact with its ZooKeeper:

```
zkcli.sh -z localhost:9983 -cmd get /clusterstate.json
```

and it returns me the information about SolrCloud. Now I'm trying to get a similar set of information programmatically, using Java.

I've tried the following:

```
SolrZkClient solrZkClient = new SolrZkClient("localhost:9983", 4000);
ZkStateReader zkStateReader = new ZkStateReader(solrZkClient);
System.err.println(zkStateReader.getClusterState());
System.err.println(zkStateReader.getClusterState().getLiveNodes());
```

But unfortunately [zkStateReader.getClusterState()](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_10_3/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/common/cloud/ZkStateReader.html#getClusterState%28%29) returns `null`.

In the log output I see the following:

```
2015-04-23 15:19:04 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5-1392090, built on 09/30/2012 17:52 GMT
2015-04-23 15:19:04 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:host.name=emre-ubuntu
2015-04-23 15:19:04 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_25
2015-04-23 15:19:04 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2015-04-23 15:19:04 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
...
2015-04-23 15:19:04 INFO  ZooKeeper:438 - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:9983 sessionTimeout=4000 watcher=org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager@3b22cdd0
2015-04-23 15:19:04 INFO  ConnectionManager:207 - Waiting for client to connect to ZooKeeper
2015-04-23 15:19:04 INFO  ClientCnxn:966 - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:9983. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-04-23 15:19:04 INFO  ClientCnxn:849 - Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:9983, initiating session
2015-04-23 15:19:04 INFO  ClientCnxn:1207 - Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:9983, sessionid = 0x14ce5f89eec000d, negotiated timeout = 4000
2015-04-23 15:19:04 INFO  ConnectionManager:102 - Watcher org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager@3b22cdd0 name:ZooKeeperConnection Watcher:localhost:9983 got event WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null path:null type:None
2015-04-23 15:19:04 INFO  ConnectionManager:225 - Client is connected to ZooKeeper
null
```

Am I missing something? How can I get that information using Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see that you are trying to get solrcloud cluster state using java., You could try something like this..

```
CloudSolrServer server = new CloudSolrServer("192.112.21.21:9983");
server.setZkConnectTimeout(15*60*1000); 
server.setZkClientTimeout(15*60*1000); 
server.setParser(new BinaryResponseParser()); 
server.setRequestWriter(new BinaryRequestWriter());
CollectionAdminRequest adminRequest = new CollectionAdminRequest(); 
adminRequest.setAction(CollectionAction.CLUSTERSTATUS); 
CollectionAdminResponse adminResponse = adminRequest.process(server); 
System.out.println(adminResponse.toString());
```

And the output will be something like this for a collection with 2shards.,

```
{
    responseHeader={
        status=0,
        QTime=1650
    },
    cluster={
        collections={
            collection1={
                shards={
                    shard1={
                        range=80000000-ffffffff,
                        state=active,
                        replicas={
                            core_node2={
                                state=active,
                                core=collection1_shard1_replica1,
                                node_name=192.112.21.21: 8983_solr,
                                base_url=http: //192.112.21.21: 8983/solr,
                                leader=true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    shard2={
                        range=0-7fffffff,
                        state=active,
                        replicas={
                            core_node1={
                                state=active,
                                core=collection1_shard2_replica1,
                                node_name=192.112.21.21: 8984_solr,
                                base_url=http: //192.112.21.21: 8984/solr,
                                leader=true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                maxShardsPerNode=1,
                router={
                    name=compositeId
                },
                replicationFactor=1,
                autoAddReplicas=false,
                autoCreated=true
            }
        },
        live_nodes=[
            192.112.21.21: 8983_solr,
            192.112.21.21: 8984_solr
        ]
    } }
```

Answer (score 5):

@Vijay the CloudSolrServer is deprecated. Instead use CloudSolrClient. Thank you for your tip. From there I reached this solution. Thank you.

If you didn't resolved this, I have a solution for you.
This method I need it too in order to check the replicas from another systems.

```
final CloudSolrClient server = new CloudSolrClient("localhost:2181");
try {
  //probably this is the line that missed from your code...
  server.connect();

  final ClusterState clusterState = server.getZkStateReader().getClusterState();
  final DocCollection collection = clusterState.getCollection("collection1");
  //EVRIKA! collection object
  // and get the leader of the collection...pretty easy.
  Replica leader = clusterState.getLeader("collection1", "shard1");
} catch (Exception e) {
  // do your stuff
} finally {
  server.close();
}
```

I hope that my lately answer will be useful for others.

Nice day.

Comment: Thanks Buddy.. Will put that in use from now on!